# How to use intent in fragment? (Xamarin & MVVMCROSS)

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am try to call Activity of LoginView class from fragment, but I am facng some error.
My code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity (), LoginView);
StartActivity(intent);
```

the error on getActivity and on LoginView please suggest what I use so that it works.

Comment: Why not use `ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>();` ?

Comment: In the ViewModel of your fragment.

Comment: Not sure what error you mean, but your code for creating a new intent is wrong, you should be passing the activity type as a 2nd argument, not the view, something like `var intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(LoginActivity))`

Comment: Yes Florian I done that, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity, typeof(LoginActivity));
StartActivity(intent);
```